# double integration with limits

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

let s be a positive real number.....evaluate

$\displaystyle\int _0^1\int _y^1\frac{x^s}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$

Evaluate:

$\int _a^b\:\int _a^b\:\sqrt{x^2+y^{2\:}dxdy}$

D= (x,y):x^2+y^2 <= y>=x>=0

Comment: What is the meaning of: "D= (x,y):x^2+y^2 <= y>=x>=0"?

Comment: D= (x,y):x^2+y^2 <= y>=x>=0 is the equation for the limits....and not (1,0) and (1,y)...that is wrong, i made a mistake.....there is no limits there.....it should be D which represents D= (x,y):x^2+y^2 <= y>=x>=0

Comment: @user117012 Then you need to edit the question so it is clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: FYI, the title as it is has no mathematical meaning. You either 'evaluate' integrals or 'integrate twice'

Comment: thank ou guys...i just edited it...its my first time and i posted it very quickly, did not realize i made mistakes here and thee, thank you for the hint

Answer (score 2):

About the second integrals, we can consider the region $D$ as it is in the plot:

$$D:=x^2+y^2\le y, x\le y, x\ge0$$

[image]

The equation $x^2+y^2=y$ can be written as $x^2+(y-1)^2=\frac{1}4$ which its polar associated equation is $r=\sin(\theta)$. So we get: $$A=\int_{\theta=\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{r=\sin(\theta)}r\times rdrd\theta$$

Comment: Good choice, to go polar! +1

Comment: @B.S.: Nice approach and graphics! +1

Answer (score 1):

A much better approach for this problem is changing the order of integration. The tricky part for these problems is working out out the new limits of integration to ensure you're still integrating over the plane region. If you have trouble visualizing what it should be, drawing pictures always helps. Switching the order we get,

$$\int_0^1\int_y^1\frac{x^s}{x^2+y^2}dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{x^s}{x^2+y^2}dydx$$.

After integrating with respect to $y$, you should come out with a really nice function of $x$ that you can integrate.

---

In the original integral, we first integrate w.r.t. $x$ from $y$ to $1$, and next integrate w.r.t to $y$ from $0$ to $1$. Thus, the 2-dimensional region is described by the inequalities: $$y\leq x \leq 1,\\ 0\leq y \leq 1,$$

or equivalently as one line of inequalities,

$$0\leq y \leq x \leq 1.$$

If you graph this region you will see a right triangle:

[image]

Comment: ok i sort of get it.....however, with the actual integrating itself...which method are you referring to??

Comment: You mean the integration wrt $y$?

Comment: i mean how do i even start to integrate this lol ..... now that you mentioned changing the limits.....how do i start to integrate? can you show some steps as how to do this please?

Comment: @user117012 First you should note I just corrected a confusing typo. Your original integral had $x$ first then $y$, but I transcribed that wrong and had $dydx$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: my bad...its my fist time typing into this site and i was not sure how to accurately input the question...i trust it is now correct and, i can see in your reply it is the correct form on the left hand side

Comment: @user117012 Oh no, I meant I made a mistake in $my$ answer, which may or may not have confused you more depending on if you saw it. :p

Comment: @user117012 Alright, so you say you don't even know where to start. Let's start at the very beginning then. Can you sketch the region in the xy-plane that we're integrating over?

Comment: i believe so....quarter of circle with intersection at 2 for both x and ?

Comment: no no sorry i am talking about the other question......and answer to you is no, i do not know how to sketch that either

Comment: @user117012 I added a bit more info on the limits of integration. Take some time to let the reasoning sink in, and see if you can finish up the problem. If you still haven't got it in an hour, I'll fill in the missing the steps.

Comment: ok thank you the graph makes more sense...however, i am not sure how to approach the integration parts, even with having the limits......x^s/x^2+y^2 ? do i rearrange it so its not a fraction? if so how do i proceed with i? if not please advise me more..also thank you for your help and time, appreciate it

Comment: thank you David....i understand everything except the part which i have to integrate.....due to the fact there is x^s and its a fraction.....i try but i doubt i will be successful...i tried substitution, by parts....does not seem to come out right

Comment: @user117012 Remember, we switched the order of integration to allow us to integrate w.r.t. $y$ first, and when you're integrating over the variable $y$, $x$ is just a constant. One more hint: $\int_0^x\frac{x^s}{x^2+y^2}dy=x^s\int_0^x\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dy$. Look familiar yet?

Comment: i seee....ok let me have a go now with that hint.....i think its possible to do it now :) ....thank you, i keep you posted